# objective-c selector, do other languages such as c++, python, ruby, java, javascript have similar thing?

Tags: java, python, c++, objective-c, ruby

```
// main.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Car.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

@autoreleasepool {
    Car *porsche = [[Car alloc] init];
    porsche.model = @"Porsche 911 Carrera";

    SEL stepOne = NSSelectorFromString(@"startEngine");
    SEL stepTwo = @selector(driveForDistance:);
    SEL stepThree = @selector(turnByAngle:quickly:);

    // This is the same as:
    // [porsche startEngine];
    [porsche performSelector:stepOne];

    // This is the same as:
    // [porsche driveForDistance:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:5.7]];
    [porsche performSelector:stepTwo
                  withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:5.7]];

    if ([porsche respondsToSelector:stepThree]) {
        // This is the same as:
        // [porsche turnByAngle:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:90.0]
        //              quickly:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        [porsche performSelector:stepThree
                      withObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:90.0]
                      withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Step one: %@", NSStringFromSelector(stepOne));
}
return 0;
}
```

**For objective-c selector, do other languages such as c++, python, ruby, java, javascript have similar thing?
thanks**

Comment: Look up 'reflection' for Java and C#

Comment: I could answer that question with a simple YES and it would be a correct answer. If you expect some more useful information then ask appropriately. Maybe you want to know how equivalents in certain languages look like? Ask specifically for that language, not just "... for C++, Javascript, Java, etc....". This has no end.

Comment: WinAPI have. It's SendMessage function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. C++ has pointer to members which perform a similar function - these identify an instance method which can then be invoked supplying the object to call the method on and the arguments, similar semantics (modulo Objective-C using dynamic binding and C++ using late binding) but rather different syntax to `performSelector:withObject:` etc.

The others? All the languages have descriptions available on the web...